# Rotation animation not starts immediately after launch

Tags: android, animation

I try to make animation of button rotation. The problem is that it starts only after approx 1 second after I launch it

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    rotate.setDuration(1000);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(0);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    performSync.setAnimation(rotate);
```

How to make it start immediately ?

Comment: Helpful would to be to know when in the lifecycle you call this animation and how you call it and start it.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem: added your snippet to `onCreate()` of my Activity, used a TextView and added `rotate.start();` right after your code. Rotates immediately after opening the app. So please post enough code for a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

in your res folder create xml for example name it rotate.xml and use this code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="10"
        android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

then in your activity set the animation to your view like this

```
private void startAnimations() {

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
    yourView.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

after that you can user startAnimation method anywhere you want it will start directly